Homogeneous notation for differential forms on projective space
Let $z_0, \dots, z_n$ be homogeneous coordinates for $\Bbb{P}^n$, say over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $f$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n + 1$. I have seen the following notation for differential $n$-form on projective space (Huybrechts Complex Geometry Exercise 2.4.8):
$$\sum_{j = 0}^n (-1)^{j} \frac{z_j}{f} \; dz_0 \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dz_j} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_n$$
Intuitively, it makes sense that this should give a well-defined (necessarily meromorphic) differential form on projective space, since the scalar $\Bbb{C}^\times$-action cancels out. But this does not seem rigorous: the "correct" way to understand a global section of a vector bundle is to write it down in local coordinate charts, compatible with the transition functions between charts. I am unsure what the meromorphic differential form I have written above is supposed to be in the standard affine coordinate charts. For example, my intuition would be that $\frac{z_j}{f} dz_0 \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dz_j} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_n$ should vanish on all coordinate charts besides $U_j$, since there would be a $d1 = 0$ term in each such chart, but this cannot be right because then this form would be zero almost everywhere, hence zero. Someone has already asked this about this exact exercise (How should the notation in this description of a global section of a line bundle in Huybrechts' complex geometry book be interpreted?), but the answer there does not adequately address the issue I observe and I am not sure it is a completely correct interpretation. It maybe seems that this form is only well-defined as a sum, and each individual term does not work on its own.
What does this "homogeneous differential form" notation actually mean?

Have you written this down concretely when $n=1$? Why do you say the form is $0$ almost everywhere? Also, do you know that the canonical bundle on $\Bbb P^n$ is $H^{-(n+1)}$? Is this related to your question?

@TedShifrin So how would you interpret, say, the "homogeneous form" $1/z_0 dz_0$ in local coordinates? What would it be on $U_0$ and $U_1$? I don't think there is a reasonable way to do this.

The only reasonable interpretation is that the form is supposed to refer to
$$(-1)^i \frac{1}{f(z_{0/i}, \dots, z_{n/i})} dz_{0/i} \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dz_{i/i}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{n/i}$$
on the standard coordinate chart $U_i$. Then this is compatible with the transition functions between these charts for the canonical bundle.
But I maintain a dislike for this notation. It deceives the reader into thinking that the form is well-defined because it has degree $0$, but really it is only well-defined because the different terms of the sum are compatible with each other on different coordinate charts. A similar notation involving only one term of this sum would not make sense.

The whole point (comparing with the Euler sequence) is that the different terms match up on different charts. (You're contracting the volume form $dz_0\wedge\dots\wedge dz_n$ on $\Bbb C^{n+1}$ with the Euler vector field. A single term makes no sense.) It's important to consider the complete sum $\frac 1f(z_1,dz_0-z_0,dz_1)$ to get a well-defined global form on $\Bbb P^1$ when $f$ has degree $2$. This is quite analogous to writing the Kähler form as $\frac{(z,z)(dz,dz)-(dz,z)\wedge (z,dz)}{(z,z)^2}$ with $z$ the homogeneous variable.

@TedShifrin given the number of upvotes on your comment, it might do well as an answer. Would you consider posting it as such?
